# Outdated book description of Try-Except-Finally statement

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x, python-2.5

I am following `Apress, Beginning Python from Novice to Professional` book. It is mentioned that:

> finally. You can use try/finally if you need to make sure that some
>   code (for example, cleanup code) is executed regardless of whether an
>   exception is raised or not. This code is then put in the finally
>   clause. Note that you cannot have both except clauses and a finally
>   clause in the same try statement—but you can put one inside the other.

I tried this code:

```
def someFunction():
    a = None
    try:
        a = 1 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        print 'Yesss'
        print e
    finally:
        print 'Cleanup'
        del a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    someFunction()
```

...and the output is

```
Yesss
integer division or modulo by zero
Cleanup
```

Here, I have used `except` and `finally` in the same `try` segment, haven't I? And the code works fine as expected. I can't quite get what the book says!

Someone please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: As the accepted answer says, your book is out of date. In fact it is more than 5 years out of date. There is *a lot* that has changed in Python over the last 5 years. Do yourself a favour and buy a more recent book.

Comment: Throw all your books out and work directly from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org). In particular, note the version of Python for which any book/documentation applies. Be sure to skim the whatsnew list, in particular every major 2.x or 3.x version (although 2.x has now stabilized on 2.7 so this is historical).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been fixed since python 2.5, and is clearly noted in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341)

In other words, your book is incorrect / out of date

Answer (score 6):

I believe the book actually gives the example itself, hence I don't know what he meant by it exactly. As the previous answer noted, this was changed in python 2.5 so that

```
try:
    try:
        print 'something'
    except:
        print 'some weird error'
finally:
    print 'finally something
```

Is equivalent to

```
try:
    print 'something'
except:
    print 'some weird error'
finally:
    print 'finally'
```

Answer (score 1):

That book might be wrong, I'm afraid, as the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) uses all three. Maybe it's time to get a new book?

Answer (score 0):

Until python 2.4 it was not allowed to combine finally with except or else statement.
But since python 2.5, like other object oriented programming language it support the combining except blocks and a finally block.
Refer the latest python documentation